# Formal connectors of results ("in this way", "hence", "thusly" and "as follows")

Tags: word-usage, formal-language, formality

In the following examples, are the terms ("in this way", "hence", "thusly" and "as follows") **synonyms sufficiently formal** to be used in academic work with a sense of result?

> *In this way*, as this process occurs...
>   *Hence*, as this process occurs...
>   *Thusly*, as this process occurs...
>   *As follows*, as this process occurs...

Comment: Many native speakers regard 'thusly' as a pointless synonym for 'thus', and deplore its use in serious writing or speech. Also, it is an Americanism, and is likely to be greeted with raised eyebrows outside the USA.

Comment: There is no single standard for what is formal or not formal enough for a particular work or medium; this is something you can garner only by reading works similar to yours or asking someone with experience with it to review your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I completed my dissertation I would often use terms like Hence and thus (I would avoid thusly). For the sake of purely academic use, I would not use "In this way" and I would change thusly to thus. The rest would be acceptable.